# Is it possible to display a static image on VNC connections?

Tags: vnc, images

Recently, I've been getting semi-regular VNC connection attempts on my computer. It's most likely from the domain I set up a while back, but it appears to be mostly individual connection attempts, as opposed to a bot or similar. (For example, something in Beijing is trying to log into SSH as Root 24/7.)

Since this is most likely some punk script kiddie who heard that "VNC lets you remotely control computers", and immediately used his super-leet `nslookup` to begin "collecting IPs to hack", I'd like to know if there's any way to configure a VNC server to display a static image (e.g., a "No Tresspassing" sign, a shock image, etc.) instead of the usual desktop.

I'm thinking something built into the VNC server itself, as opposed to, for example, a bare-bones window manager that displays nothing but a wallpaper, in case I need to start a graphical session on the computer in question.

Comment: Don't waste your time. Block his Ip address in your firewall and don't give it a second thought.

Comment: @slm It's not always the some IP, or even the same ISP. I thing that every time a new script kiddie comes along, he decides to make an attempt or two. I'd really like to put up some sort of offensive or humorous image, to ward off (or irritate) any future VNC'ers.

Comment: As you probably could guess, this problem is experienced by many users with network exposed machines. Normally, it is solved by temporarily blocking the offending ip based on malicious behavior pattern (such as unsuccessful login retries). Consider this nice small utility for example: http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obviously possible and even rather easy to display a static image (but you definitely should not use this for the purposes you're describing). Take Xvnc for example: if you run it without any client connected, it will essentially always send a static image (as defined by root window content) to the vnc pipe. To set the root window to the desired image, use any X11 client which can set root window content, such as the venerable `xloadimage`.